# k-means algorithm for energy data against time and date

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am using Matlab 2015a.

I have got electricity consumption data to cluster it. Initially i am trying to cluster it against hours and dates. I have created three different variables, one for time, one for dates and third for data. I am unable to understand how should i combine these in a matrix form so that the loads are distributed according to time? Then i have tried to look how can i plot a line graph for k-means but i can only find scatter command graphs but no line plots.

Further how can i plot it as a 3-d plot?

Further at a later stage i want to include temperature variable aswel. But when the 4th variable is involved, what will the plot be? will it still be 3-d?
Any suggestions, links?

Comment: Don't use k-means with *time* variables because it is sensitive to scale.

Comment: Thank you @anony-Mousse! I have seen that many papers have performed k-means for this kind of analysis.

Comment: Yes, people do nonsense analysis, sometimes. But the results will be all but stable and they are not statistically sound.

Comment: Well i can have the liberty not to plot the data against a fixed time, however i can distribute a day in sections and use average of each distribution/partition, but date, temperature will be there.
Do you think K-means will work in a good way then?

Comment: k-means requires *continuous* attributes. It is not good for cyclic data (time) or discrete values (sections).

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab you can create *N*-dimensional matrices, so you can arrange your 3D data in a N*M*3 matrix (you might want to look for the `cat()` function to help you out).

There are several functions that allow you to plot in 3D, one of these is `scatter3()` which is perfect for K-Means clustering. I don't really understand which *lines* you do want to plot: K-Means is about clusters and centroids (i.e. points).

If a 4th variable is involved, you can as well create a 4D matrix. Although I reckon plotting a 4D graph isn't going to be easy. A first approach might be using several colours for your scatter points with different colours for different temperatures (or temperatures range). In this case the 5th input argument for `scatter3()` will be helpful.

Help for `scatter3()` [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html).
Help for `cat()` [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html).

Comment: Thank you. I think i should try to do some basic clustering first and then proceed for this. I am trying to simply use the code given for the fisheriris data to cluster my data. Honestly it's not working well for me. For example, I the clusters are overlaping which should not happen as per my understanding.

Comment: The way i have arranged data now is I have placed time in top row of matrix and 1 years data of one customer on that time in respective 365 columns (against every half hour which is on top of column). After one customer the next customers data is in placed similarly in the columns. Example is given below




Matrix=[T1        T2          T3
             L1t1      L1t2       L1t3
             L2t1      L2t2       L2t3
              ..          ....          ......
             L365t1  L365t2   L365t2]


DO you think this is right arrangement? If no what should i do?

Comment: Further i am confused how do i add dates in this matrix? Because matrix will change the dimensions of matrix (considering them as a feature??)
When i add another feature i.e. temperature, do i add it in second row?